# PHP Yii Framework - Controller works incorrectly?

Tags: php, web, yii, controller

I have a following controller with simple methods:

```
<?php

class SiteController extends CController
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo 'Zostala wywołana akcja Index';
    }

    public function actionPokaz()
    {
        echo 'Zostala wywołana akcja Pokaz';
    }

}
```

Now when I go to:
http://localhost/yii/test/site
It should run a actionIndex method, however I get "Object not found" info. Why is that?

What is more, I am doing everything according to the book I am reading (just started today) and book says it should work, but it doesn't. My project folder is yii/test of course, located in XAMPP htdocs.

Error looks as follows:

```
Nie znaleziono obiektu! (Object not found!)

Nie znaleziono żądanego URL-a na tym serwerze. Odnośnik na referującej stronie wydaje się być nieprawidłowy lub nieaktualny. Poinformuj autora tej strony o problemie. (Desired URL was not found on this server ...)

Jeśli myślisz, że jest to błąd tego serwera, skontaktuj się z administratorem.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15
```

It's in Polish. However I put translation in brackets.

My main.php:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        /*
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
        */
    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',

            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'site/policz/<liczba1:\d+>/<liczba2:\d+>'=>'site/policz/',

            ),
        ),


        // database settings are configured in database.php
        'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>YII_DEBUG ? null : 'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Comment: what http://localhost/yii/test/site/index giving ? and what http://localhost/yii/test/site/index?r=site/index or just http://localhost/yii/test/site/index?r=site

Comment: last 2 link can http://localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site/index or just http://localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site

Comment: @MindRoller, could you paste whole error, not just "Object not found"? It will be helpful.

Comment: I updated the question. When I go to localhost/yii/test it gives me "Zostala wywolana akcja Index" however if I go to http://localhost/yii/test/index or http://localhost/yii/test/site/index?r=site/index - I get an error. If I use this link:
 http://localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site/index or http://localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site
I get actionIndex().
But how can I get actionPokaz? In this stupid book they say just to go to http://localhost/yii/test/site/pokaz but it doesn't work. 404 error show above.

Comment: to get actionPokaz you need to use  localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site/pokaz i think i get your problem. will give my answer soon. please confirm me that Pokaz works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to first enable the url manager. So add a new file with name `.htaccess` in your test folder (not in protected).

[image]

and add this code below to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and add the `showScriptName'=>false,` into urlManager in `config/main.php` like this..

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
```

Then you can open your website with the link below
http://localhost/yii/test/site

Just always extend from `CController`, if u want to use only `Controller` then you have to created a customized base controller class with `Controller extends CController` in `protected/components`. Then all controller classes for your application should extend from this base class.

```
class SiteController extends CController
{

// your functions here

}
```

Comment: I tried extending Controller but it doesn't work aswell - forgot to mention that. Also in the book I am reading they say to extend CController no Controller. Really, no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I know I will get actionIndex under this link.In book they say I should go to yii/test/site/pokaz and it should work but it doesn't. Well I noticed that if I go to http://localhost/yii/test/index.php/site/pokaz I will get actionPokaz but why does it work like that and not the way they say in book, can you explain?

Comment: I guess add this code in your config/main.php file `'showScriptName'=>false,` in url manager area.

Comment: Still doesn't work the way I would like it to after adding 'showScriptName'=>false,

Comment: tell me in your actionIndex() or actionPokaz(), how are you rendering the page? post the full code of ur index or pokaz and also ur urlmanager from main.php

Comment: I have updated my answer, you have to add some .htaccess file. Check out my answer and apply it, i have tested and it will work for you. Mark the answer as accepted if it worked you!

Comment: Thanks, works. It worked fine for me. However, please update your answer (the part with CController and Controller - it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2):

You can access your controller actions from browser if you use url format like below

```
// for index action
localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site/index

// since index action is default for any controller, following url also return index action
localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site

// to access Pokaz action put this url in the browser
localhost/yii/test/index.php?r=site/pokaz
```

> Why like this? and Where is the problem ?

You need to understand the tutorial below. Please take you time to go through the tutorial, this is what you'll need on your every Yii 1 project even when you going to deploy your application to a hosting server. Ask in the comment section here if you dont understand anything in the tutorial

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Also make sure that Apache Module mod_rewrite is installed with your XAMPP

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. Well it's great, however why didn't the book tell me these things... This book is plainly wrong. Thanks once again, I will manage now.

Comment: Glad it works. The guide link I give that has other sections. Which I believe great resource for learning Yii. You can explore those as well. If this answer is right then mark this as right answer, That will help others to quickly find similar solutions and jump into right answer

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Controller and not CController

```
   <?php

  class SiteController extends Controller
  {
      /**
       * Declares class-based actions.
       */
      public function actionIndex()
      {
          echo 'Zostala wywołana akcja Index';
      }

      public function actionPokaz()
      {
          echo 'Zostala wywołana akcja Pokaz';
      }

  }
```

Comment: I tried extending Controller but it doesn't work aswell - just forgot to mention that.

Comment: You are  using Yii1 or Yii2 ?

Comment: It's Yii1 because the book is related to Yii1.

Comment: Overally, if I go to a directory or a file that exists in the project, I get actionIndex(). However if I choose to go to directory that does not exist I should also get actionIndex because it is default, right? Really, I read 5 pages of this book, got stuck and dunno what way to go, what is more further chapters are basing on this controller so dunno what to do.